# Fail2ban with Epoch time stamp

Tags: fail2ban

I do have a server running and in this log there are epoch time stamps
is there a way to make rules /triger for fail2ban with those time stamps?

A snippet for the log:
1588550278^connect 300: login: 
1588550278^connect 300: timeout set to 60

Peter